# Saltstack Using Jinja variables inside Jinja

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I am writing a salt state that will check the value of a registry key. This is returning 'NULL'. I suspect that my 'getregvalue' variable is not resolving with the variables i have passed to cmd.run. This works as expected when the -Path and -Name values are hardcoded. How do i pass the -Path and -Name variables dynamically correctly?

```
{% for regconfig in registryconfig.settings %}
{% set getregvalue = salt['cmd.run']('Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path regconfig.hive ~ ":\" ~ regconfig.path -Name regconfig.vname',shell='powershell') %}
{% endfor %}


c:\temp\debug.txt:
  file.managed:
    - contents: |
        {{ getregvalue |yaml(False) |indent(8) }}
```

This is the config file

```
{%- load_yaml as registrysettings %}

dev:
  settings:
    - hive: 'HKLM'
      path: 'SOFTWARE\Database Settings\dbstate'
      vname: ConnectionString


{%- endload %}

{%- set registryconfig = salt['grains.filter_by'](registrysettings,
    grain='env') %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make sure strings are quoted, and code is not:

```py
("Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path " ~ regconfig.hive ~ ":\\" ~ regconfig.path ~ " -Name " ~ regconfig.vname, shell="powershell")
```

If the path and name also need quoting for PowerShell, then include those too:

```py
("Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path '" ~ regconfig.hive ~ ":\\" ~ regconfig.path ~ "' -Name '" ~ regconfig.vname ~ "'", shell="powershell")
```

Comment: `{% set getregvalue = salt['cmd.run']("Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path " ~ regconfig.hive ~ ":\\" ~ regconfig.path ~ " -Name " ~ regconfig.vname, shell='powershell') %}`

Comment: `"Get-ItemPropertyValue : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'Settings\\dbstate'.\r\nAt line:1 char:1\r\n+ Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Database
Settings ...\r\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n
\   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ItemPropertyValue], ParameterBindingException\r\n
\   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyValueCommand"` . I am getting this error, maybe because there is a space character in the path?

Comment: Probably. It needs to be quoted properly.

Answer (score 0):

`{% set getregvalue = salt['cmd.run']("Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path '" ~ regconfig.hive ~ ":\\" ~ regconfig.path ~ '" -Name '" ~ regconfig.vname ~ "'", shell='powershell') %}`

Thanks to @Orangedog for pointing me in the right direction. Quoting the strings AND the arguments solved this for me.

Comment: This is just a copy of my answer...

Comment: Sorry..i had already posted before i saw your answer. And I accepted your answer.